# binding functions with objects to jQuery 'change' event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you specify a function (with or without parameters) in the DOM via onChange, you are limited to static paramters. E.g.

```
<select id="blah" onChange="doSomething(3);">
```

However, jQuery lets you dynamically define and assign functions to event handlers, such as 'change'.

See the example below:

```
function addRow(customObject) {
  << Create TR containing a select named "#someSelect + customObject.id" >>

  // Demo
  $("#someSelect" + customObject.id).change(function() {
    changeSomething(customObject)
  });
}
```

My question is - essentially - will this work? I am using a specific instance o
f an object in my jQuery change event handler. Will that particular instance of customObject (wherever it lies) always be bound to this event handler callback?

customObject is initialized at load, and is one of many. For that particular select box, I always want it to be linked to that object.

New to jQuery. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have several rows of items. Each is represented by an object. I just want to make sure that when someone modifies one of the rows via HTML, that the underlying object (bound to the callback function) is properly updated.

I am looking for something like this, conceptually a mapping between:

```
Row 1 - customObject1
Row 2 - customObject2
Row 3 - customObject3
```

... such that if I modify one of the HTML elements (e.g. change the select box) in row 3, that behind the scenes, customObject3 is modified

Comment: It will work. You just need to be sure to write your object's id's (i.e. write all your html) before to run that script. You'll probably need to run that script at the end, not in the header.

Comment: *"will this work?"* Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: When you say "in the DOM", it's actually in the HTML which gets converted to a handler in the DOM, and you can reference global variables. They don't need to be static values.

Comment: if `customObject.id` equals (for instance) 2 and you have an element with id `someSelect2`, then yes, it will "work". But I'm not sure it will do what you're expecting, as I can't really make out what exactly it is that you're ultimately trying to accomplish here.

Comment: *"Will that particular instance of customObject (wherever it lies) always be bound to this event handler callback?"* The instance itself won't be bound. The function references the variable, so it'll get whatever instance happens to be assigned to that variable when the handler runs.

Comment: You can always create custom attrubute like "data-custom-id" with $(selector).attr('data-custom-id',id) or alternatively by $(selector).data(key,value) and use it later in change event handler to create selector for needed cusom object that is bound.

Global variables ain't good idea.

Comment: customObject changes. This isn't a global variable. This is why I want to make sure, that when I create a 'change' event handler for a specific row, the object instance (customObject) is always modified whenever a particular row is modified

Comment: Not sure if when you say it "changes", if you mean the object is mutated or the variable gets updated to reference a different object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work in case `customObject.id` is defined before adding the listener and you intent the listener itself to be bound to that specific element without moving it around.

From your question I understand that `customObject.id` is dynamic as in can change its value and depending on this value, the listener can listen on different element. In this case, you'd have to use a bit more general selector and check the value inside the listener itself:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    if(this.id === 'someSelect' + customObject.id)
        return myCallback(e);
});
```

Edit:

The problem lies in accessing the `customObject` inside the listener. It uses the current content, not the content it used to have when you added the listener.

Easiest solustion I know is:

```
var select = $("#someSelect" + customObject.id);
select.customObject = customObject; /* save customObject to the select itself */
select.on('change', function() {
    changeSomething(this.customObject); /* don't use global object but its own */
});
```

Comment: the ID never changes. It represents the ID of an object. Each row has an underlying object. I just want to make sure that when someone modifies the HTML, that the correct instance of the underlying object is acted upon

Comment: Well, if it doesn't change, it isn't dynamic and you can set it like `$('#someSelectID')`, no?

Comment: That isn't what I am worried about

Comment: Oh dear, what are you worried about, then?

Comment: If the contents of customObject are routinely changing, will the instance (at the time I create the change event handler) always be bound to the change event handler for a specific item?

Comment: Well, judging by how you modified your question you haven't even tried it! Because you would find out you had it right from the start.

When you bind a listener to an element, it stays bound to that element until you remove it, it can't move itself.

Comment: I have tried it! But I have some weird side effects happening, which I was looking to see if they were due to this, or some other cause. TL DR: I am really confused right now. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: Oh I see now, the problem is not in the listener but in how you use customObject inside it, will change the answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55870/discussion-between-newtoms-and-jakub-michalek).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your patience my friend.

Comment: `this.customObject` will be `undefined` in your example.